# INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE ao tentar instalar apk

Tags: android

Estou tendo este problema ao instalar no meu celular uma nova versão de uma aplicação Android que estou construindo e, pelo que já pesquisei, pode ser facilmente resolvido desinstalando a aplicação antiga e instalando a nova. Porém, se eu fizer isso irei perder os dados do app antigo, coisa que eu não queria. Teria alguma maneira de resolver este problema sem perder os dados existentes?

Comment: Pode haver mais de uma razão para isso acontecer. Indique o que de relevante alterou entre as duas versões.

Comment: Não foi alterado nada estrutural (nome de packages, adição de novas bibliotecas, absolutamente nada disso), apenas algumas funcionalidades básicas.

Comment: Esses dados do seu app antigo, estão em banco de dados(tipo sqlite))? Tem como exportar esses dados?

Comment: Dados em arquivos de texto e no banco de dados. Não teria como exportar pois existem várias pessoas usando a aplicação, sendo que cada um deles tem seus próprios dados em seus telefones

Comment: Isso não pode ser assinaturas diferentes? Tipo duas chaves distintas.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a série de respostas em [**INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE when I try to install compiled .apk on device**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11891848/1518921)

Esta mensagem quer dizer que o aplicativo já esta instalado:

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]

Isto pode ocorrer por talvez ter instalado o aplicativo de outra maneira, ou instalou via root ou via playstore, você pode tentar desinstalar via adb:

```
adb uninstall <nome do pacote>
```

Ou então você pode desinstalar pelo próprio celular, vá até <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Apps</kbd> e selecione seu App e clique em <kbd>Uninstall</kbd>

> [image: celular]

Versões mais recentes do Android basta arrastar o App e no topo da tela aparece o <kbd>Uninstall</kbd> (ou <kbd>Desinstalar</kbd>):

> [image: drag uninstall]
>
> **Nota:** Se aparecer apenas o Remove significa que não é possível desinstalar

---

### Teria alguma maneira de resolver este problema sem perder os dados existentes?

Existem algumas, ainda sim se o problema ocorre a todos momento você deveria checar o que esta ocorrendo, provavelmente estava tentando instalar o app por meios diferentes, ou o teu ADT esta desatualizado.

> **Nota:** Se aparecer apenas o Remove significa que não é possível desinstalar

- Clique em <kbd>Setting</kbd>
- Vá até <kbd>Back up & sync</kbd>:

  > [image: back up & sync]
- Ligue o backup clicando em ON (se estiver off):

  > [image: ligando backup]
- Clique em <kbd>Backup All</kbd>

Ou então pode usar um aplicativo como:

- [Backup Your Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.backupyourmobile)
- [Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup)

Comment: Infelizmente não respondeu a minha pergunta, mas obrigado mesmo assim

Comment: @flpn pode instalar um APP para fazer backups, ou um para navegar nas pastas e copiar os dados ou simplesmente sincronizar os dados com sua conta da PlayStore.